# Negative look-ahead in Go regular expressions

Tags: regex, go, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to use negative look-aheads in Go.

The following regular expression: `BBB(((?!BBB).)*)EEE`

http://rubular.com/r/Zw1vopp1MF

However, in Go I get:

```
error parsing regexp: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax: `(?!`
```

Are there any alternatives?

Comment: What's your expected output that you want?

Comment: I want to match everything in between a BBB and EEE. However, if there is an instance with BBB something BBB something else EEE . I only want to match "BBB something else EEE"

Comment: Only thing you can do is http://regex101.com/r/aM5oU3/4 if you are very sure that standalone `B` or `BB`  is not there in the string.

Comment: If you can, use the answer, because life is easier with just the Go stdlib. (Fewer compilation and distribution headaches and other cgo issues.) If you badly need Perl-compatible regexps for some reason, you could look at one of the PCRE adapters out there, like https://github.com/glenn-brown/golang-pkg-pcre

Answer (score 51):

Negative lookahead isn't supported for technical reasons, specifically because it conflicts with the O(n)-time guarantees of the library. See the [golang-nuts group discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/7qgSDWPIh_E) about this, as well as the Caveats section in [Regular Expression Matching in the Wild](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp3.html).

You can express the regular expression you've described without negative lookahead:

```
BBB([^B]|B[^B]|BB[^B])*EEE
```

Here's an [example](https://play.golang.org/p/3k7c7bCNFc) to demonstrate:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`BBB([^B]|B[^B]|BB[^B])*EEE`)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", re.FindAllString("BBB EEE BBB..BBB...EEE", -1))
}
```

Comment: @hwnd's solution is simpler.  I'm assuming that when you say `BBB`, you don't really mean `BBB` literally, but rather some arbitrary sequence of Beginning characters, followed by a sequence of Ending characters.  But perhaps you are looking for `"BBB"` and `"EEE"`.  :P

Comment: Hey, this is brilliant!

Answer (score 6):

[dlclark/regexp2](https://github.com/dlclark/regexp2) is a port of the .NET framework's `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` engine.

> There are some fundamental differences between .NET strings and Go strings that required a bit of borrowing from the Go framework regex engine as well. I cleaned up a couple of the dirtier bits during the port (regexcharclass.cs was terrible), but the parse tree, code emmitted, and therefore patterns matched should be identical.

It's name dropped at the end of the [lengthy discussion about O(n) regular expressions](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/7qgSDWPIh_E/aKBGgoj8AAAJ), and is caveated:

> However, I would advise caution as there are benefits to the re2-based engine that are not provided by more full featured engines with lookarounds.  If you have the option then stick with the stdlib.

The cost of features is a slower implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Based off your examples and your expected output, the following would work.

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`BBB([^B]*)EEE`)
```

<kbd>[**GoPlay**](http://play.golang.org/p/zv3przYsNj)</kbd>

Comment: Seems that this would fail for something like:  `BBB xx B xx EEE`

Comment: It may be a solution, but to a different question. The question was about negative lookahead.

Comment: Yes, which is not supported.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by @dyoo,

```
string(?:(?!endString).)*endString
```

can be polyfilled as (where *`char n`* means the `n`th char of *`string`*):

```
string
(?: # Match 0+ groups, each either
  # doesn't start with the first char of string,
  [^<char 1>]
|
  # share the first, but not the second,
  <char 1>[^<char 2>]
|
  # share the first two, but not the third,
  <char 1><char 2>[^<char 3>]
|
  # ...
|
  # share the first n - 1, but not the nth,
  <char 1>...<char n-1>[^<char n>]
)*
endString
```

Structure in non-ASCII art (where `X` denotes a difference):

```
┌──┬──┬──┬─────────────┬────┬──┐
│C1│C2│C3│     ...     │Cn-1│Cn│
└──┴──┴──┴─────────────┴────┴──┘
├──┼──┼──┼─────────────┼────┼X   C1C2C3...Cn-1[^Cn]
├──┼──┼──┼─────────────┼X   │    C1C2C3...[^Cn-1]
│  │  │  │     ...     │    │          ...
├──┼──┼X │             │    │    C1C2[^C3]
├──┼X │  │             │    │    C1[^C2]
├X │  │  │             │    │    [^C1]
```

Another representation using nested non-capturing groups:

```
(?: # Match 0+ groups, each consists of
  # the first char, followed by either
  <char 1>
  (?:
    # the second char, followed by either
    <char 2>
    (?:
      # the third char, followed by either
      <char 3>
      # ...
        (?:
          # the (n-1)th char, followed by
          <char n-1>
          (?:
            # something that is not the nth char
            [^<char n>]
          )
        |
          # something that is not the (n-1)th char
          [^<char n-1>]
        )
      # ...
    |
      # or something that is not the third char
      [^<char 3>]
    )
  |
    # or something that is not the second char
    [^<char 2>]
  )
|
  # or something that is not the first char
  [^<char1>]
)*
```

Structure in non-ASCII art (where `X` denotes a difference and `┬` a branch):

```
┌──┬──┬──┬─────────────┬────┬──┐
│C1│C2│C3│     ...     │Cn-1│Cn│
└──┴──┴──┴─────────────┴────┴──┘
├┬─┼┬─┼┬─┼─────────────┼┬───┼─X  C1C2C3...Cn-1[^Cn]
││ ││ ││ │             │└X       C1C2C3...[^Cn-1]
               ...                     ...
││ ││ │└X│                       C1C2[^C3]
││ │└X│  │                       C1[^C2]
│└X│  │  │                       [^C1]
```

These two do the same thing. For long strings, the second solution will be substantially shorter. For example, let `<div>` and `</div>` be the start and end mark, correspondingly:

```
<div  <span>Foo</span>   div>
```

will be separated as (where `_` denotes a space; [with colors](https://regex101.com/r/iv8BL4/1)):

```
┌───────┬───┬────┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬────┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│ <div_ │ _ │ <s │ p │ a │ n │ > │ F │ o │ o │ </ │ s │ p │ a │ n │ > │ _ │ _ │ _ │ d │ i │ v │ > |
└───────┴───┴────┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴────┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

As one can observe from the two structures above, there is a repeating pattern, which means the regex can be generated programmatically. Here's such a program, written in pseudocode:

```
function escape(string)
  return string.replace(/[-/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')
end

function escapeBracket(char)
  return char == ']' ? '\\]' : char
end

function polyfill(string)
  regex = []

  for index from 0 to string.length do
    # string[0] included, string[index] excluded
    branch = escape(string.slice(0, index)) + '[^{escapeBracket(string[index])}]'
    regex.append(branch)
  end
  
  return '(?:{regex.join('|')})*'
end

polyfill('BBB')    # '(?:[^B]|B[^B]|BB[^B])*'
polyfill('<div>')  # '(?:[^<]|<[^d]|<d[^i]|<di[^v]|<div[^>])*'
```

...or:

```
function polyfill2(string)
  reversedString = string.reverse()
  regex = ''

  for index from 0 to string.length do
    char = reversedString[index]
    firstBranch = regex ? escape(char) + regex + '|' : ''
    secondBranch = '[^{escapeBracket(char)}]'
    regex = '(?:{firstBranch}{secondBranch})'
  end

  return regex + '*'
end

polyfill2('BBB')    # (?:B(?:B(?:[^B])|[^B])|[^B])*
polyfill2('<div>')  # (?:<(?:d(?:i(?:v(?:[^>])|[^v])|[^i])|[^d])|[^<])*
```

Try them on regex101:

- `polyfill`:

  - [`BBB`](https://regex101.com/r/yI0iGu/1) (PCRE2: 711 steps)
  - [`<div>`](https://regex101.com/r/DY5DdC/1) (PCRE2: 4021 steps)
- `polyfill2`:

  - [`BBB`](https://regex101.com/r/yI0iGu/2) (PCRE2: 814 steps)
  - [`<div>`](https://regex101.com/r/DY5DdC/2) (PCRE2: 4734 steps)
- Negative lookaheads:

  - [`BBB`](https://regex101.com/r/yI0iGu/3) (PCRE2: 991 steps)
  - [`<div>`](https://regex101.com/r/DY5DdC/3) (PCRE2: 5887 steps)

Playground:

```js
const [p1, p2, p3] = document.querySelectorAll('div');
const [start, end] = document.querySelectorAll('input');
const data = document.querySelector('#data');

start.addEventListener('input', inputHandler);
end.addEventListener('input', inputHandler);

start.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));


function inputHandler() {
  const escaped = [escape(start.value), escape(end.value)];
  
  [
    [p1, polyfill],
    [p2, polyfill2],
    [p3, lookahead]
  ].forEach(([element, fn]) => {
    element.textContent = escaped.join(fn(start.value));
  });
  
  data.textContent = generateData(start.value, end.value);
}

function generateData(start, end) {
  const data = [];

  const middleLength = 10 + Math.random() * 30 | 0;
  const middle = [...Array(middleLength)].map(() => {
    const original = (Math.random() > 0.5 ? end : start);
    return original[Math.random() * original.length | 0];
  }).join('');
  
  for (let i = 0; i < start.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < end.length; j++) {
      data.push(
        start + start.slice(0, i + 1) +
        middle +
        end.slice(-j - 1) + end
      );
    }
  }
  
  return data.join('\n');
}

function escape(string) {
    return string.replace(/[-/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
}

function escapeBracket(char) {
    return char === ']' ? '\\]' : char;
}


function polyfill(string) {
    const regex = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        const branch = escape(string.slice(0, i)) + `[^${escapeBracket(string[i])}]`;
        regex.push(branch);
    }

    return `(?:${regex.join('|')})*`;
}

function polyfill2(string) {
    const reversedString = [...string].reverse();
    let regex = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        const char = reversedString[i];
        const firstBranch = regex ? escape(char) + regex + '|' : '';
        const secondBranch = `[^${escapeBracket(char)}]`;
        regex = `(?:${firstBranch}${secondBranch})`;
    }

    return regex + '*';
}

function lookahead(string) {
  return `(?:(?!${escape(string)}).)*`;
}
```

```css
label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1em;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

label > :nth-child(n + 2) {
  align-self: stretch;
  font-family: monospace;
}

input {
  padding: 1.5em 1em;
  height: 0;
}

div {
  word-break: break-all;
}

#data {
  height: 5em;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <span>Start/end:</span>
  <input type="text" value="[foo-bar(baz)qux]">
  <input type="text" value="[foo-bar(baz)qux]">
</label>

<label>
  <span>Polyfill:</span>
  <div id="p1"></div>
</label>

<label>
  <span>Polyfill2:</span>
  <div id="p2"></div>
</label>

<label>
  <span>Negative lookahead:</span>
  <div id="p3"></div>
</label>

<label>
  <span>Random text:</span>
  <textarea id="data"></textarea>
</label>
```

*(Disclaimer: I don't know Go. This answer was written as suggested by @markalex at [q/76035959](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76035959))*

Answer (score 0):

Based on Andy's answer. There is another mod by h2s05 that implements extended regex https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/h2so5/goback AND it implements the same api interface as the normal regexp library, handy if you don't want refactor to support the api differences in dlclark's library