# How to split the string in such way?

Tags: arrays, regex, string, go, split

I need to split a string like "aa bb cc dd ee ff" in golang to

```
["aa bb" "bb cc" "cc dd" "dd ee" "ee ff"]
```

I'm trying this:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile("[a-z]+\\s+[a-z]+")
fmt.Printf("%q\n", re.FindAllString("aa bb cc dd ee ff", -1))
```

But it returns:

```
["aa bb" "cc dd" "ee ff"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func pairs(s string) []string {
    var p []string
    fs := strings.Fields(s)
    if len(fs) >= 2 {
        p = make([]string, 0, len(fs)-1)
        for i, f := range fs[1:len(fs)] {
            p = append(p, fs[i]+" "+f)
        }
    }
    return p
}

func main() {
    s := "aa bb cc dd ee ff"
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", s)
    p := pairs(s)
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", p)
}
```

Output:

```
"aa bb cc dd ee ff"
["aa bb" "bb cc" "cc dd" "dd ee" "ee ff"]
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You forget to say that it's a repeating pattern:</strike>

```
([a-z]+\\s+[a-z]+)*
```

---

The solution (`(?=([a-z]{2}\s+[a-z]{2})*)`) needs lookahead which is [not available in go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26792316/2307070)

Comment: @nanolab true. I've found a solution with lookahead but it's not supported by go...

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate with a `bufio.Scanner`:

```
package main

import (
   "bufio"
   "strings"
)

func abc(data []byte, eof bool) (int, []byte, error) {
   if eof {
      return 0, nil, nil
   }
   a := -1
   for b, c := range data {
      if c == ' ' {
         if a >= 0 {
            return a+1, data[:b], nil
         }
         a = b
      }
   }
   return len(data), data, nil
}

func main() {
   s := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader("aa bb cc dd ee ff"))
   s.Split(abc)
   for s.Scan() {
      println(s.Text())
   }
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/bufio#Scanner.Split