# custom pattern to drop bots when importing logs into influxdb

Tags: influxdb, logparser, telegraf

I import apache logs into influxdb with telegraf and logparser plugin

I want to filter out all the logs from bots, so I setup a custom pattern with a regex that only match user-agent that don't contain the words "bot" and "crawl" :

```
NOBOT ((?!bot|crawl).)*
CUSTOM_LOG_FORMAT %{CLIENT:client_ip} %{NOTSPACE:ident} %{NOTSPACE:auth} \[%{HTTPDATE:ts:ts-httpd}\] "(?:%{WORD:verb:tag} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:http_version:float})?|%{DATA})" %{NUMBER:resp_code:tag} (?:%{NUMBER:resp_bytes:int}|-) %{QS:referrer} "%{NOBOT:agent}"
```

but it doesnt work, zero metrics are being imported into influxdb

the regex seems ok and it works fine when I test it here : http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match

Just to be sure I tried a simpler regex :

```
BOT .*?bot.*?
CUSTOM_LOG_FORMAT %{CLIENT:client_ip} %{NOTSPACE:ident} %{NOTSPACE:auth} \[%{HTTPDATE:ts:ts-httpd}\] "(?:%{WORD:verb:tag} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:http_version:float})?|%{DATA})" %{NUMBER:resp_code:tag} (?:%{NUMBER:resp_bytes:int}|-) %{QS:referrer} "%{BOT:agent}"
```

and it works, telegraf only import logs from bots but I want the opposite, I don't see what's wrong with `((?!bot|crawl).)*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are not getting an error message, but unfortunately Go doesn't support negative look-aheads:

https://play.golang.org/p/Kq5N2FgG6_

```
Hello, playground
panic: regexp: Compile(`((?!bot|crawl).)*`): error parsing regexp: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax: `(?!`

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x133400, 0x1050a140)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x720
regexp.MustCompile(0x149f1b, 0x11, 0x1, 0xb)
    /usr/local/go/src/regexp/regexp.go:237 +0x1a0
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox426143344/main.go:10 +0xe0
```

I'd recommend opening an issue on the github repo to return an error message in these cases.

As for making the match you're trying to do, this might be helpful: [Negative Look Ahead Go regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26771592/negative-look-ahead-go-regular-expressions)

Comment: Thanks, ticket opened : https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/issues/2178#issuecomment-268200504