# Regex to match strings that do not start with www in golang

Tags: regex, go, traefik

I have the following RegEx `^http:\/\/(?!www\.)(.*)$`

Expected behavior:

```
http://example.com - Match
http://www.example.com - Does not match
```

It looks like `golang` does not support negative lookahead. How can I rewrite this RegEx to work on `golang`?

**UPDATE**

I'm not coding using golang, I'm using [Traefik](https://traefik.io) that accepts a Regex (golang flavor) as a config value, so basically I have this:

```
regex = "^https://(.*)$"
replacement = "https://www.$1"
```

What I want is to always add **www.** to the URL, but **NOT** if the URL has it already, otherwise it would become **www.www.***

Comment: I know nothing of golang which is why this is a comment, but can't you do a match for `/^http:\/\/www\./` in an if statement and if it doesn't match look for `http://example.com`

Comment: Please refer the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26771592/negative-look-ahead-go-regular-expressions) for more information

Comment: I have the same problem where I'm using re2 as a regex engine without the full expressiveness of Golang (Terraform's `regex()` function.) Trying to use variable validation in Terraform 0.13 to ensure that users don't pass a string that begins or ends with certain words — i.e., regex for does NOT match _string_ (not just characters).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're really bent on creating a negative lookahead manually, you will need to exclude all possible `w` in the regexp:

```
^https?://(([^w].+|w(|[^w].*)|ww(|[^w].+)|www.+)\.)?example\.com$
```

This regexp allows any word with a dot before `example.com`, unless that word is just `www`. It does so by allowing any word that does not start with `w`, or, if it starts with `w` it is either just that `w` or followed by a non-`w` and other stuff. If it starts with two `w`, then it must be either just that or followed by a non-`w`. If it starts with `www`, it *must* be followed by something.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tT04sG/1)

The clarification makes this much much easier. The approach is to always (optionally) match `www.` and then to put that back in the replacement always:

Search:

```
^http://(?:www\.)?(.*)\b$
```

Replace:

```
http://www.$1
```

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/tT04sG/3)

Comment: It works partially. The problem is that I need to capture whatever domain name that comes after http:// excluding "www."

Comment: Moreover, that matching text should be on the first capturing group ($1). Do you think it's possible to achieve that?

Comment: How about always matching the `www.` and then putting it back no matter what? I'll update my answer above

Comment: Genious! Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

Golang uses the RE2 regex engine, which [doesn't support look arounds of any kind](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Since you are dealing with URLs, you can simply parse them and inspect the host part:

```
package main

import (
    "net/url"
    "strings"
    "testing"
)

func Match(s string) bool {
    u, err := url.Parse(s)
    switch {
    case err != nil:
        return false
    case u.Scheme != "http":
        return false
    case u.User != nil:
        return false
    }

    return !strings.HasPrefix(u.Host, "www.")
}

func TestMatch(t *testing.T) {
    testCases := []struct {
        URL  string
        Want bool
    }{
        {"http://example.com", true},
        {"http://wwwexample.com", true},
        {"http://www.example.com", false},
        {"http://user@example.com", false},
        {"http://user@www.example.com", false},
        {"www.example.com", false},
        {"example.com", false},
    }

    for _, tc := range testCases {
        if m := Match(tc.URL); m != tc.Want {
            t.Errorf("Match(%q) = %v; want %v", tc.URL, m, tc.Want)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I'm not using golang directly, so I can't do that - I need to specify a RegEx (golang flavor) inside Traefik (https://traefik.io) config.