# negative lookahead

Tags: regex, go

I'm trying to write a regex that matches anything but one word(themagicword in this example), coming from the perl/python world I would do it with a negative lookahead:  `^(?!themagicword).*`
How would I achieve this in golang as this doesn't seem to work in golang.

Comment: The stdlib regular expression engine does not support lookaheads.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to match strings that do not start with www in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52648425/regex-to-match-strings-that-do-not-start-with-www-in-golang)

Comment: If you are able to use CGO, you can use one of a number of `pcre` packages [like this one](https://github.com/d4l3k/go-pcre). Just google "pcre golang" or something

Comment: Shouldn't that be: `^(?!.*themagicword).*` or `^(?!themagicword$).*` ? And wouldn't it be more efficient to do `$haystack !~ /themagicword/` ?

Comment: It sounds like you just need `if input != "themagicword" { ... }`, without regex. Or maybe `if !strings.HasPrefix(input, "themagicword") { ... }`.

Comment: See this recent answer to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/54903727/1153938

Answer (score 0):

"matches anything but one word" is equivalent to "matches (not word)" which is equivalent to "not (matches word)". So just match the word you want to exclude and then return the inverse:

```
hasmagic, _ := regexp.MatchString("themagicword", "haystack")
matched := !hasmagic
```

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram like that?