# Regex for matching everything until first occurence of string in Golang flavor

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

> my-name-host1.host2.host3.com:80

I'm looking for a regex which matches everything until the string `-host1.host2.host3.com:80`, i.e. the result shall be:

> my-name

My current regex in JavaScript seems to be working. The problem is that I need this regex in a "Golang flavor".

https://regex101.com/r/ebSTuq/1

When switching it to Golang I get this regex with a pattern error:
`.*(?=\Q-host1.host2.host3.com:80\E)`

> The preceding token is not quantifiable.

Comment: Use `(.*?)-host1\.host2\.host3\.com:80`. Or probably just `^[^-]+-[^-]+`.

Comment: Golang's re2 doesn't support lookarounds, you can check supported syntaxes [here](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go regex engine is RE2, and [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) [does not support lookarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26771592/negative-look-ahead-go-regular-expressions).

Actually, you do not need the lookahead: use the non-greedy dot pattern at the start, capture it into Group 1 and use the rest of the pattern as is to check the right hand context:

```
str := `my-name-host1.host2.host3.com:80`
re := regexp.MustCompile(`(.*?)-host1\.host2\.host3\.com:80`)
match := re.FindStringSubmatch(str)
fmt.Println(match[1])
```

Output: `my-name`, see the [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/tvn4BHMTZ9x).

Note the use of the [`FindStringSubmatch` function](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindStringSubmatch) that allows access to captured substrings.

Also, see the [Go regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r0bF9x/1).