# Exclude measurements using regex in influxql

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I have an influxql query used in grafana as follows:

```
SELECT mean("value") FROM /^concourse\.(worker*|web*).*\.system_mem_percent$/ WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval), * fill(null)
```

This works as expected, I get only the results of measurements with `worker...` or `web...` in it.

I'm trying to now build the inverse query of this. I.E all measurements that do not have `worker...` or `web...` in it.

I'll need to be able to do this with regex on measurements itself. (Assume no tags)

How could this be achieved in influxql (influxdb 1.7).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need negative lookahead in your regexp. But InfluxDB uses [Golang’s regular expression syntax](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/), where negative lookahead is not supported.

You may use workaround with more complicated regexp with negated character classes - see [Negative look-ahead in Go regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26771592/negative-look-ahead-in-go-regular-expressions)

But I would go with better InfluxDB design and I would use tags. It is also recommended approach https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/concepts/schema_and_data_layout/#avoid-encoding-data-in-measurement-names