# How to exclude particular IPV4 addresses using regex in Go?

Tags: regex, go

I am able to use negative lookahead in Javascript to not match certain IPs like 127.0.0.1 but I am unable to use the same for my microservice that runs in Go.

This is the regex I use in Javascript -

```
^(?!127\.0\.0\.1)(([1-9])|([1-9][0-9])|([1][0-9][0-9])|(2[0-1][0-9])|(22[0-3]))\.(((([0-9])|([1-9][0-9])|([1][0-9][0-9])|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))\.){2})(([1-9])|([1-9][0-9])|([1][0-9][0-9])|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))$
```

Answer (score 1):

Negative lookahead is not support in Go's regular expressions. See the question, [Negative look-ahead in Go regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26771592/negative-look-ahead-in-go-regular-expressions)

Might want to look at using the package [`cidranger`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/yl2chen/cidranger) instead.