# RE2-compatible regex to get only one substring from string with a set of substrings inside of it

Tags: regex, re2

I have a string in format `@@@substring1@@@substring2`, that comes from a black-box.

`substring1` could be empty or not, `substring2` is always non-empty. `@@@` is a delimiter and I could change it via black-box settings. `substring1` and `substring2` never contain `@@@` inside of them.

I need to get the first substring from this string, e.g. from `@@@substring1@@@substring2` I need to get `substring1`, from `@@@@@@substring2` I need to get `substring2`.

My black-box allows to process the string with [RE2 regex](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax). I can't use external stuff like `cut`, `sed`, `awk` etc. Is it possible to do that with regex only?

My thoughts are as follows:

[regex](https://regex101.com/r/tggsUA/1) `@@@([^@]+)`

- will produce 1 match with 1 group `@@@@@@substring2` - that is what I need
- will produce 2 matches with 1 group each for `@@@substring1@@@substring2` - that is not what I need, I need only 1 match

Lookahead / lookbehind assertions `(?=re)`, `(?!re)`, `(?<=re)`, `(?<!re)` and `\K` syntax are not supported in [RE2 regex](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Comment: Right, there is no lookahead support in RE2, but it is not quite clear yet: can there be more substrings? If yes, then something like `^.*?(@@@[^@]*)?(@@@[^@]*)$` can work to get one or two captures at the end of the string. Can you use code to parse the regex match result? If yes, Something like `(?:@@@[^@]*)+$` can work, you will just need to remove the first `@@@` and then split with `@@@`.

Comment: `^.*?(@@@[^@]*)?(@@@[^@]*)$` matches the whole string `@@@substring1@@@substring2` - https://regex101.com/r/HtmcNK/1

Comment: There are always 1 (`@@@@@@substring2`) or 2 (`@@@substring1@@@substring2`) substrings, cannot be more than 2. No, I can't parse matches with additional "after-regex" logic.

Comment: It is not important what is matched, it is important what is captured. And if you have no access to code, you are stuck, this problem has no plain regex solution with RE2.

Comment: Yes, you are right, whole-string matching is okay here. The problem is that "substring1" would be in capturing-group 1, and "substring2" would be in capturing-group 2, even if "substring1" is empty. So I cannot just "perform regex and use `${1}` as a result".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax)-flavored solution based on @InSync answer:

`(?:^@@@|^)@@@([^@]+).*$`

- for `@@@substring1@@@substring2` it matches the whole string with just one capturing group `${1}` containing `substring1`
- for `@@@@@@substring2` it matches the whole string with just one capturing group `${1}` containing `substring2`

Comment: This can be simplified as [`^(?:@@@)?@@@([^@]+).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/XIjQDp/4).

Answer (score 1):

Match the trailing delimiters as well so that `substring2` would not be able to match if `substring1` matched:

```
@@@           # Match triple '@'
([^@]+)       # followed by a non-empty sequence of non-'@' character, which we capture,
(?:@@@|$)     # then another triple '@' or the end of string.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/XIjQDp/1).

This, of course, relies on a capturing group. If you cannot use capturing groups, then there is no answer.

Also, just for fun, here's a PCRE solution:

```
^                      # Match at the start of the string
(?(?=@@@(.+?)@@@.+)    #                     if it exists
  @@@\1                # the first substring
|                      # or
  @{6}\K.+             # the second substring (preceded by 6 '@' which we forfeit).
)                      #
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/XIjQDp/2).

...and an extension of the first regex above which accepts substrings containing no more than three consecutive `@` (see my explanation for the middle expression [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76064059/21305238)):

```
^(?:@@@)?@@@
((?:@(?:@(?:[^@]|$)|[^@]|$)|[^\n@])+)
(?:@@@|$)
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/XIjQDp/3).

Comment: Unfortunately `?=` syntax is not supported in ER2: "(?=re) before text matching re (NOT SUPPORTED)" https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax . But the first example helped me to find a working solution for my problem. I will post it separately. Thank you!

Comment: @AntonioK I said the second is for PCRE. I know it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... I need to get the first substring from this string, e.g. from `@@@substring1@@@substring2` I need to get `substring1`, from from `@@@@@@substring2` I need to get `substring2`. ...
>
>
>
> ... Is it possible to do that with regex only?"*

Yes, you can use the following pattern.

```
@{3,6}(.+?)(?:@|$)
```

Yours is correct also, you just need to define when to stop the capture.

```
@@@([^@]+?)(?:@|$)
```